# how to find foreign keys constraints?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, foreign-key

I have a table called abs with primary key absId, this is used as a foreign key in couple of tables which I don't know. Is there a way that I can find out how find the names of those  tables in which the primary key absId is referenced? I'm using Oracle 10g as the database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ABS` is the parent table in the foreign key relationship and the name of the primary key constraint is `ABS_PK`, you can identify all the foreign key constraints that reference this primary key using the `DBA_CONSTRAINTS` view.  Something like

```
SELECT owner, constraint_name, table_name
  FROM dba_constraints
 WHERE r_owner = <<owner of ABS_PK>>
   AND r_constraint_name = 'ABS_PK'
   AND constraint_type   = 'R'
```